# What is wrong with this code that saves value objects?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two entities and two value objects - Employee, Card, Employee Number & Card Number. The relationship between Employee and Card is a one-to-many. I create an instance of Employee and an instance of Card like so and save them to the database...

```
EmployeeRepositoryHibernate employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepositoryHibernate();
employeeRepository.setSessionFactory();
employeeRepository.getSession().beginTransaction();

EmployeeNumber employeeNumber = new EmployeeNumber("MNO");
Location location = new Location("Room 1");
CardNumber cardNumber = new CardNumber("1");

Employee employee = new Employee(employeeNumber, location);        
    Card card = new Card(cardNumber, "1111", employee);

employeeRepository.getSession().save(employee);
employeeRepository.getSession().save(card);

employeeRepository.getSession().getTransaction().commit();
employeeRepository.getSession().close();
```

Except, it won't save, the following error message is shown... I can save an employee, but the message is thrown when I try to save a related card... the mysql database isn't relational yet.. both tables are separate...

**Problem fixed:** required related tables.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'employeeNumber' doesn't have a default value
```

Here are the two Hibernate XML mapping files for Card and Employee...

Card

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">
  <class name="model.Card" table="Card">

        <id name="CardID" type="long">
        <column name="CardID" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

   <component name="cardNumber" unique="true">   
       <property name="number" column="cardNumber"/>  
    </component>

  <many-to-one name="employee" class="model.Employee" fetch="select">
        <column name="EmpID" not-null="true"></column>
</many-to-one>

<property name="PIN" column="PIN"/>
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Employee

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">
  <class name="model.Employee" table="employee">

 <id name="EmpID" column="EmpID">
      <generator class="org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator"/>
    </id>

   <component name="employeeNumber" class="model.EmployeeNumber" > 
       <property name="number" column="employeeNumber" type="string"/>  
    </component>


<component name="location">   
   <property name="location" column="Location" type="string"/>  
</component>

 <set name="cards" inverse="true" cascade="all">
        <key>
                <column name="EmpID" not-null="true"></column>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="model.Card"/>
    </set>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you show the object `Employee`?

Answer (score 0):

One of these might help:

- Add a default value to the column `employeeNumber`

  `ALTER TABLE 'table_name' ALTER 'employeeNumber' SET DEFAULT NULL`
- Use `auto increment` if you are using `employeeNumber` as a `primary key`.
- Supply value to the `employeeNumber` column during insertion.